# SSMS v19 "broken" - cursor + keyboard shotcuts

Tags: ssms

So, bit of a weird one!  I have a very fresh install of Windows 11 Business Edition and have installed SSMS v19 so I can administer my databases (no custom config apart from enabling line-numbers).

If I open a .sql file (sometimes it's the first one, sometimes it's the 3rd or 4th), it will disable all of my normal keyboard shortcuts and I can place the cursor anywhere within the file.  I can't do anything with it anymore and the only way to fix is to close it all down and restart SSMS (after which it's fine for a bit and then might do it again).

This doesn't feel right, considering I've been using SSMS for MANY years and this is the first time I've ever come across this.  Anybody else experienced this and knows how to fix (apart from going to another management suite from a different company)?

The commands via the file menu still seem to work, but all keyboard shortcuts do random things and I can't select anything with the cursor because it seems to be 'floating'.

Comment: I assume you've tried uninstalling SSMS and reinstalling it? If you have any add-ins have you tried removing those?

Comment: Yes, already tried that.  There are no add-ins - it's a fresh install.